# general idea and maybe example on graph

Tags: graph

I'm looking for a general idea (and maybe some code example or at least pseudocode)
Now, this is from a problem that someone gave me, or rather showed me, I don't have to solve it, but I did most of the questions anyway, the problem that I'm having is this:

Let's say you have a directed weighted graph with the following nodes:

```
AB5, BC4, CD8, DC8, DE6, AD5, CE2, EB3, AE7
```

and the question is:
how many different routes from C to C with a distance of less than x. (say, 10, 20, 30, 40)
The answer of different trips is: CDC, CEBC, CEBCDC, CDCEBC, CDEBC, CEBCEBC, CEBCEBCEBC.

The main problem I'm having with it is that when I do DFS or BFS, my implementation first chooses the node and marks it as visited therefore I'm only able to find 2 paths which are CDC and CEBC and then my algorithm quits. If I don't mark it as visited then on the next iteration (or recursive call) it will choose the same node and not next available route, so I have to always mark them as visited however by doing that how can I get for example CEBCEBCEBC, which is pretty much bouncing between nodes.

I've looked at all the different algorithms books that I have at home and while every algorithm describes how to do DFS, BFS and find shortest paths (all the good stufF), none show how to iterate indefinitively and stop only when one reaches certain weight of the graph or hits certain vertex number of times.

Comment: Is CDCDCDCDC (or similar) not also a valid solution?

Comment: sure, if it doesn't exceed the predetermined weight limit, so in your example the limit would have to be 72

Comment: To clarify: is this to do with the mutability of your data representing nodes? Had you considered a recursive algorithm that uses immutable representations (such as you'd do with Functional Programming)?

Answer (score 2):

So why not just keep branching and branching; at each node you will evaluate two things; has this particular path exceeded the weight limit (if so, terminate the branch) and is this node where I started (in which case log my path history to an 'acceptable solutions' list); then make new branches which each take a step in each possible direction.

Comment: because you may end up with infinite loop, the goal is to find all the solutions..why don't you try implementing it first..

Comment: I don't see it; if we are summing up the weight and there are no zero-weight cycles in the graph ... every branch will terminate for finite weight limits.

Comment: Mikeb is right. For all weights > 0 and x a finite value, his algorithm will terminate.

Comment: I believe there are 280 paths for this DG, limit 100

Answer (score 1):

You should not mark nodes as visited; as MikeB points out, CDCDC is a valid solution and yet it revisits D.

I'd do it lke this:

```
Start with two lists of paths:
 Solutions (empty) and
 ActivePaths (containing one path, "C").
While ActivePaths is not empty,
 Take a path out of ActivePaths (suppose it's "CD"[8]).
 If its distance is not over the limit,
  see where you are by looking at the last node in the path ("D").
  If you're at "C", add a copy of this path to Solutions.
  Now for each possible next destination ("C", "E")
   make a copy of this path, ("CD"[8])
   append the destination, ("CDC"[8])
   add the weight, ("CDC"[16])
   and put it in ActivePaths
 Discard the path.
```

Whether this turns out to be a DFS, a BFS or something else depends on where in ActivePaths you insert and remove paths.

No offense, but this is pretty simple and you're talking about consulting a lot of books for the answer. I'd suggest playing around with the simple examples until they become more obvious.

Comment: so basically instead of search for the next path you're taking the exisiting paths CD, CE, etc. In other words you are iterating over known edges

Comment: I'm iterating over the edges leading away from the node (D->C and D->E in my example). I don't know what you mean by "known edges" or "search for the next path".

Answer (score 0):

In fact you have two different problems:

- Find all distinct cycles from C to C, we will call them `C_1`, `C_2`, ..., `C_n` (done with a DFS)
- Each `C_i` has a weight `w_i`, then you want every combination of cycles with a total weight less than N. This is a combinatorial problem (and seems to be easily solvable with dynamic programming).